# Does deleting a wifi network also delete the ca certificate (assuming there was one to begin with)?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

Recently I deleted a wifi network on my Samsung Android. I do not remember if that network required me to instal a certificate back when I first joined it. When I check all my credentials in the settings, I do not see any under “user”, just “system”. So, I wanted to check if the fact that you deleted the wifi network also deleted the certificate. If so, that would explain why I do not see one. If not, that would tell me that network never had me install one.

Answer (score 1):

This is a software-specific question, sufficiently so that "Samsung Android" isn't necessarily sufficient to answer it. However, the odds are extremely high that:

1. No, deleting a WiFi network won't interact with the certificate store at all. That's something that somebody *could* program in and I've never seen it claimed that any particular version does or doesn't have this feature, but I would not expect it at all.
2. Unless this was a WPA-Enterprise network, using TLS for submitting authentication and using a self-signed cert for TLS, you almost certainly wouldn't have had the opportunity to install one. Even if it was, you might not! Not all WPA-Ent networks use TLS, in which case they won't have a cert at all. Not all that do use TLS self-signed certs (they can't use public-CA-signed certs but they could in theory* use certs signed by an internal CA whose cert your device already trusts, in which case it won't need to check with you for the network's cert). Last but not least, at least some systems just automatically trust the cert for WPA-Ent without giving you a chance to decide (this is exploitable but it's not *realistically* like people are going to distinguish between a valid and a fraudulent self-signed cert, so there's an argument that letting them "decide" is security theater and not worth investing dev effort into in almost all cases).

* I don't know if Android, of any version, supports chain-of-trust for WPA-Ent certs or not.